# Is there any alternatives to using covariant type in contravariant position?

Tags: scala, generics, covariance, contravariance

I am looking for a pattern for creating new instances from existing ones such that I can compute the ultimateBase of a Tile by traversing the hierarchy above it. I tried the following but get "Covariant type A occurs in contravariant position" on parameter *base* of *buildTile* method. Is there an alternative pattern to building instances that depend on prior instances?

```
trait Color
trait Blue extends Color
trait Green extends Color

trait Tile[+A] {
  def declaredBase: Option[(Double, Tile[A])]

  final val ultimateBase: Option[(Double, Tile[A])] = ??? // Some implementation, not important

  // Can't be protected[this]
  def buildTile(name: String, multiple: Double, base: Tile[A]): Tile[A]
}

case class BlueTile(name: String, declaredBase: Option[(Double, Tile[Blue])]) extends Tile[Blue] {
  override def buildTile(name: String, multiple: Double, base: Tile[Blue]): Tile[Blue] = {
    // Something more complicated here
    this
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

1) You can declare contravariant position's type separately, and implement it in subclass:

```
trait Tile[+A] {
  type T <: A
  def declaredBase: Option[(Double, Tile[A])]

  final val ultimateBase: Option[(Double, Tile[A])] = None // Some implementation, not important

  // Can't be protected[this]
  def buildTile(name: String, multiple: Double, base: Tile[T]): Tile[A]
}

case class BlueTile(name: String, declaredBase: Option[(Double, Tile[Blue])]) extends Tile[Blue] {
  type T = Blue
  override def buildTile(name: String, multiple: Double, base: Tile[T]): Tile[Blue] =
  {
    println(base.declaredBase)// Something more complicated here
    this
  }
}

scala> val x = new BlueTile("", None)
x: BlueTile = BlueTile(,None)

scala> val a: Tile[Color] = new BlueTile("", None).buildTile("", 1.0, x) //covariance works
None
a: Tile[Color] = BlueTile(,None)
```

It works in this particular case because you really can specify the type T eventually.

2) Another approach is to add `def buildTile` implicitly:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait Tile[+A] {  
  def declaredBase: Option[(Double, Tile[A])]
  final val ultimateBase: Option[(Double, Tile[A])] = None // Some implementation, not important 
}

case class BlueTile(name: String, declaredBase: Option[(Double, Tile[Blue])]) extends Tile[Blue]

implicit class BuildFromBlue(t: Tile[Blue]) {
  def buildTile(name: String, multiple: Double, base: Tile[Blue]): Tile[Blue] = {
    println(base.declaredBase)// Something more complicated here
    t
  }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait Tile
defined class BlueTile
defined class BuildFromBlue

scala> val x = new BlueTile("", None)
x: BlueTile = BlueTile(,None)

scala> val a: Tile[Color] = new BlueTile("", None).buildTile("", 1.0, x) //covariance works
None
a: Tile[Color] = BlueTile(,None)
```

3A) Last alternative is covariance through existential types. You can declare `Tile[A]` as invariant, but require `Tile[_ <: A]` when needed:

```
trait Tile[A] {
  def declaredBase: Option[(Double, Tile[A])]
  def buildTile(name: String, multiple: Double, base: Tile[A]): Tile[A]
}

case class BlueTile(name: String, declaredBase: Option[(Double, Tile[Blue])]) extends Tile[Blue] {
  override def buildTile(name: String, multiple: Double, base: Tile[Blue]): Tile[Blue] = this
}

scala> val x = new BlueTile("", None)
x: BlueTile = BlueTile(,None)

scala> val a: Tile[_ <: Color] = new BlueTile("", None).buildTile("", 1.0, x)
a: Tile[_ <: Color] = BlueTile(,None)
```

1,2,3A) But you can't use it in contravariant position after casting to bigger type `Tile[Color]`:

```
scala> a.buildTile("", 1.0, a)
<console>:18: error: type mismatch;
found   : Tile[_$1(in value res20)] where type _$1(in value res20) <: Color
required: Tile[_$1(in value a)]
          a.buildTile("", 1.0, a)
                               ^
```

3B) You can just bind `base` with contravariant existential type to achieve that:

```
trait Tile[+A] {
  def declaredBase: Option[(Double, Tile[A])]
  def buildTile(name: String, multiple: Double, base: Tile[_ >: A]): Tile[A]
}

case class BlueTile(name: String, declaredBase: Option[(Double, Tile[Blue])]) extends Tile[Blue] {
  override def buildTile(name: String, multiple: Double, base: Tile[_ >: Blue]): Tile[Blue] = {println(base.declaredBase); this}
}

scala> val x = new BlueTile("", None)
x: BlueTile = BlueTile(,None)

scala> val a: Tile[Color] = new BlueTile("", None).buildTile("", 1.0, x: Tile[Blue])
None
a: Tile[Color] = BlueTile(,None)

scala> a.buildTile("", 1.0, a) //you can do it now
None
res23: Tile[Color] = BlueTile(,None)
```

It works as `[_ >: A]` actually says that you don't need [liskov-substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) for `base` itself. It will allow `buildTile` be used from `Tile[Color]`. But this approach will unbound `base` to `Tile[_ >: Color]` to satisfy liskov-substitution for `Tile[+A]` itself:

```
scala> a.buildTile("", 1.0, a: Tile[Any]) //Tile[Any] also works
None
res27: Tile[Color] = BlueTile(,None)
```

So I would recommend to restrict `A` to the `Color` (or maybe somewhere in subtraits od `Tile`):

```
trait Tile[+A <: Color]{...}
...

scala> a.buildTile("", 1.0, a) 
None
res33: Tile[Color] = BlueTile(,None)

scala>  a.buildTile("", 1.0, a: Tile[Any])
<console>:18: error: type arguments [Any] do not conform to trait Tile's type parameter bounds [+A <: Color]
           a.buildTile("", 1.0, a: Tile[Any])
                                   ^
```